# Android emulator

Tags: eclipse, android-emulator, touch

How can i test touch enable app using eclipse with android emulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/gestures.html

Comment: thanks KevinDTimm. Can you pls tell me how can give touch input to emulator. Because i cant give them by touching emulator screen using mouse.